# How do I find equilibrium points of a partial differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do i find the critical points of this fourth order differential equation.

**\begin{equation} D\left(\frac{d^4w}{dx^4}+\frac{d^4w}{dy^4}+\frac{d^4w}{dz^4}\right)+(\rho_m-\rho_c)gw=q-P\left(\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}+\frac{d^2w}{dy^2}+\frac{d^2w}{dz^2}\right). \label{bilaplaciano31} \end{equation}**

D, P, q, **$\rho_m$**, **$\rho_c$**, g are constants.

The boundary conditions are free.

Does anyone know how to get all the critical values for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I solve the equation with  finite differences placing a sinusoidal load distribution, obtaining an approximate solution.                                      
  I also thought about finding the critical values of  **\begin{equation} Dw''''+(\rho_m-\rho_c)gw=q-Pw''. \label{bilaplaciano31} \end{equation}** https://www.overleaf.com/read/hcpnbdcqctdh
to simplify the problem but I'm not sure if it's okay